# Is there a vba code which opens a msgbox when cell value is not equal to "X"?

Tags: excel, vba, range, msgbox

Im not vba savvy so I thought this is the best place to ask. My aim is to have a msgbox appear when a specific cell is not equal to 'X' value. Here is the code I have below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myCell As Range

For Each myCell In Range("G4:G160")
    If myCell.Value <> 17521 Then
        MsgBox "INCORRECT SKU RECHECK PALLET AND INFORM SUPERVISOR"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next myCell
End Sub
```

The cell value is taken from another cell so not manually entered in.
When I run this macro it appears everytime i change cells or click. Also appears when the number is correct. I only need this msgbox to appear only when it is not equal to the value.

I would also like to have the message to be in the colour red. If this is easy enough please let me know what to do or change. Biggest learning curve for me as I always avoided vba code.

EDIT: Please look at link below. Barcodes to the right 1,2 and 3 are correct to be scanned into B4 and so on and the wrong ones 4 and 5. Im hoping for msgbox or userform to visually show only the wrong ones. If correct ones are entered then no pop up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axI5s.jpg)
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvRcvV5GEpBXnRIrzT2xDTv0iTQh?e=tV3LeN

Comment: To get your red text, simply create your own dialog box as a userform. About the other part of your question. What exactly are your trying to achieve. Currently you are checking 10 cells against a single value. If any of those does *not* equal `17521` you'll get your pop-up. In your question you are talking about singular instead of plural. Which is it?

Comment: Also, if these values change due to formulas (*"not manually entered"*) you can't capture it through `Worksheet_Change` (on those specific cells) so I guess this is why you went with `SelectionChange`? If so, it's not suprsing you'll get your pop-up when you click another cell etc.

Comment: So why don't you simply run a `Worksheet_Change` event on just `B4`? First you'd check for a `Intersect` result between `Target` and `B4`, if so, check if the scanned result holds `17521` and act accordingly? If a formula can, VBA can too! This would prevent constant popping up messages and checking when changing other cells.

Comment: I highly recommend to add sample data to your question instead of linking files. People really should not click on that link to download a file they don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be right. Once you select another cell in your target sheet, this code runs and will never show the msgbox if **all values** in the range "G4:G160" are equal to 17521. If it appears, there is certainly at least one value <>17521.
I recommend to use the `Change Event` instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In Range("G4:G160")

        If (Not IsEmpty(myCell)) And myCell.Value <> 17521 And myCell.Value <> "" Then

            MsgBox "INCORRECT SKU RECHECK PALLET AND INFORM SUPERVISOR", vbCritical

            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next myCell
End Sub
```

About the red color of the msgbox, you cannot change the color of a msgbox. You have two options:

1. Instead of red color, show a `Critical` icon as:

```
MsgBox "INCORRECT SKU RECHECK PALLET AND INFORM SUPERVISOR", vbCritical
```

In this case, you'll see something like this:
[image]

2. Create a UserForm and adjust its font color and then show it instead of MsgBox.
   If you want to use the second option, please let me know and then help you create it.

Comment: the vbCritical works a treat, thank you! But seeing how UserForm seems to be more visually useful how do I add that to the code instead of msgbox?

Comment: You're welcome :). Then, to add a UserForm, please see [this](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html) illustrative example which explains all steps in detail. Then, if my answer has been able to solve your problem, please accept this answer as a solution to help others with a similar question. Thanks!

Comment: Hey common dear @MarcHipolito. Never apologize for asking questions. We are all here to help each other and ask questions. Special thanks to StackOverflow managers :-). And about your new problem, I modified my answer to handle the case where a cell is empty. Please see my answer and see if that helps. I'm ready to hear more from you.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your workbook with me? I need it to regenerate the error and find the origin of that. My email address is saeedsayyadipour@gmail.com

Comment: Your error is caused by the DataValidation criterion. Because your criterion only accepts a whole number, but your formula says that if the **IF** condition not met, put ```""``` which is not a whole number. In brief, your data validation criterion is inconsistent with the formula in column G. I think as you are controlling values in column G via VBA, you don't need the datavalidation anymore. Simply remove it and all will work fine.

Comment: @MarcHipolito, as your formula sets ```""``` when the **IF** condition is false, hence that cell is no more blank and it contains a ```""```. Therefore, our constraints in the code are violated and a message is shown. I modified my answer. This should resolve your problm.

Comment: YES! This works wonders! Solved! Thank you for all the help! Now I have to make a new thread in how to add userform instead of msgbox haha BUT Thank you very much!

Comment: Good!! Happy to hear your problem is solved! Create the thread, I'll send you a complete answer :)). I've just started writing a simple example for your next thread lol.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279174/how-to-add-userform-into-this-code-instead-of-msgbox  this is the new thread for userform. Thank you once again! I couldnt have done this without you and the Stack overflow team!

Comment: OK!! I'll just write all steps for you ;-)