# How to add userform into this code instead of msgbox?

Tags: vba, userform, msgbox

I currently have this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myCell As Range

For Each myCell In Range("G4:G160")

    If (Not IsEmpty(myCell)) And myCell.Value <> 17521 And myCell.Value <> "" Then

        DisplayUserForm

        Exit Sub
    End If

Next myCell
End Sub
```

and have this for my userform

```
Sub DisplayUserForm()

Dim form As New WarningBox
form.LOL.Caption = "INCORRECT!"
form.Show
Set form = Nothing
```

End Sub

What else must I do in order for this to appear instead of msgbox to alert whoever is entering data will be showing "INCORRECT!" in bold and Surrounded by red.
Please see image below of what I am trying to show 
[image]

Comment: Just replace `MsgBox "INCORRECT SKU RECHECK PALLET AND INFORM SUPERVISOR", vbCritical` with `DisplayUserForm`.

Comment: When the userform is displayed they are able to edit the word in it, can the editable function be removed when it appears? or am i to use another type of pop up box/code instead of userform?

Comment: Use a label having dimensions exactly as the form. Choose the font size and color you need (Black - Forecolor) and BackColor = red. You can play with its `SpecialEffect`, `Border` properties...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1. Insert a new Form by right-clicking on your VBA project and selecting `UserForm` under the `Insert` option.
   [image]
2. Click once on the created form and then press the ``F4`key to open the`Properties``` window.
   [image]
3. On the `Properties` window, the default name for your form is `UserForm1`. Change it to any new value as you want (e.g., WarningBox)
4. From the `ToolBox` window, drag and drop a `Label` on your form and adjust its size, font, font color, and all other properties that exist on the `Properties` window. Please rename the label to `message`. I will use this name later when calling the form to be shown.
   [image]
5. If you want, like step 4, add a `CommandButton` to your form and change its name to for example `okButton` and adjust other properties as you want.
   [image]
6. Double click on the button to write the code for this button. Write the code as follows:

```
Private Sub okButton_Click()

    'Close the form
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

7. Now, modify your `DisplayUserForm()` sub as follows:

```
Sub DisplayUserForm()

    Dim form As New warningBox
    form.message.Caption = "write your message here"
    form.Show
    Set form = Nothing

End Sub
```

All will be done as you want!

Comment: The sub ```AllowCircular()``` has no corresponding ```End Sub```.

Comment: One another thing: the ```DisplayUserForm()``` sub in your question differs from that in the picture. Which one has you implemented?

Comment: It seems that you've put the ```Workbook_Open()``` sub in ```Module1```! It should be in the ```ThisWorkbook``` module.

Comment: Would you share your workbook with me? My email is SaeedSayyadipour@gmail.com

Comment: THANK YOU! WORKS WONDERS! All working now! I found my mistakes

Comment: Happy to hear that! Good Luck Marc

Comment: If you don't mind can you please take a look at a new question of mine and see what I need. You have already seen my workbook so thought you might know more of what im talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683624/how-to-have-msgbox-appear-when-cell-value-hasnt-changed-in-30secs-or-1min-etc

Answer (score 0):

Marc: if your "Incorrect" message is the "LOL" object whose caption you modify with the code `form.LOL.Caption = "INCORRECT!"`, it will be editable if it is a TextBox object. Saeed Sayyadipour's example shows using a Label object, instead, that will not be editable by the user (and I 'second' his advice about the "OK" button).

Also, though, since the event tells you which cells were changed by defining the "Target" range object, do you really need to loop through all of G4:G160, since only the cells within Target were changed by the user? Perhaps use `For Each MyCell in Intersect(Target,Range("G4:G160"))`, or perhaps add these lines where appropriate:

```
Dim AffectedCells as Range
...
Set AffectedCells=Intersect(Target,Range("G4:G160"))
...
Set AffectedCells=Nothing
```

and change your loop to:

```
For Each myCell in AffectedCells
...
Next myCell
```

If there is no overlap between the changed range (Target) and your G4:G160, nothing happens and your code exits quickly.