# Is there a vba code which opens a msgbox when cell value is not equal to a specific cell?

Tags: excel, vba, messagebox

I'm new to using vba so I wanted to know if there's a way I can get excel to show a message box when the value of a cell is not equal to another cell in my worksheet?

I saw this code being used for when the cell is not equal to a specific value:
[Is there a vba code which opens a msgbox when cell value is not equal to "X"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62256463/is-there-a-vba-code-which-opens-a-msgbox-when-cell-value-is-not-equal-to-x/62257060#62257060?newreg=52303c017c1c43c1bd1b70ce230b4988)

```
type herPrivate Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In Range("G4:G160")

        If (Not IsEmpty(myCell)) And myCell.Value <> 17521 And myCell.Value <> "" Then

            MsgBox "INCORRECT SKU RECHECK PALLET AND INFORM SUPERVISOR", vbCritical

            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next myCell
End Sube
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What's `another cell`? Is it fixed or dynamic?

Comment: A basic description of the posted code would be: **When** the user changes **any cell's value on the worksheet** containing this code, (**what?**) the code will search for a cell in the range `G4:G160` which is not blank and is different than `17521`. If found, **the search is ended** (`Exit Sub`) and the message is displayed. Now, in a similar fashion, more accurately describe what kind of functionality you require. Focus on the **when?** (e.g. the user changes the value in `A1`) and the **what?** (e.g. display a message if not equal to `A2`).

Comment: @VBasic200
"another cell" is a fixed cell that contains a sum formula. The value in this cell must be equal to the value of another cell that contains an index(match) formula. If the values of these two cells are different, I want the user to get a warning message

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome  "another cell" is a fixed cell that contains a sum formula.

Comment: Try: `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(): If CStr(Me.Range("A1").Value) <> CStr(Me.Range("A2").Value) Then: MsgBox "The values are different!", vbExclamation: End If: End Sub` in the sheet module of e.g. `Sheet1` (not `Module1` and not `ThisWorkbook`). Each colon (`:`) denotes a new line.

Answer (score 1):

It could something like this - a lookup function:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell    As Excel.Range

    If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
        For Each Cell In Range("G4:G160")
            If Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then
                If Cell = Target Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    
    If Cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "INCORRECT SKU RECHECK PALLET AND INFORM SUPERVISOR", vbCritical
    Else
        Set Cell = Nothing
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Calculate: Two Cells Contain Different Numbers

- This code runs on each calculation of the worksheet's formulas.
- Both cells contain formulas and if any of their results is not a number, a message is displayed.
- If they both contain numbers and they are not equal, a different (the 'required') message is displayed.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1` (Not Standard Module e.g. `Module1` or `Thisworkbook` Module)**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    
    Const Cell1 As String = "A1"
    Const Cell2 As String = "A2"
    
    Dim Val1 As Variant, Val2 As Variant
    
    With Me ' reference the worksheet in a sheet module
        Val1 = .Range(Cell1).Value
        Val2 = .Range(Cell2).Value
    End With
    
    If VarType(Val1) <> vbDouble Then
        MsgBox "The calculated value in cell """ & Cell1 _
            & """ is not a number.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub ' the 1st value is not a number (not caring about 'Val2')
    End If
    
    If VarType(Val2) <> vbDouble Then
        MsgBox "The calculated value in cell """ & Cell2 _
            & """ is not a number.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub ' the 2nd value is not a number (when 'Val1' is a number)
    End If
    
    If Val1 = Val2 Then Exit Sub ' the numbers are equal
    
    MsgBox "The calculated values " & Val1 & " in cell """ & Cell1 & """ and " _
        & Val2 & " in cell """ & Cell2 & """ are not equal!", vbExclamation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008 for your help this works perfectly!